# SQL Server VARCHAR(MAX) and DB Size very high

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am storing the HTML in the database. No, this is not a dynamic web application, but a template that gets stored in database and finally gets printed.

This template is VARCHAR(MAX) and has on average of 700K records (7 lac records). There are about 28K records stored in database and the DB size is already 21GB.

I figured that it is the Template column causing the DB size to be big. The size of this column in database is about 17GB.

Do you think I can add any compression logic to compress and then save this data in database? I know it will be add up little overhead for compression, but i doubt if it is going to be big.

I cannot store database outside of SQL as this will make the sensitive data available to anyone having file share permissions.

Any other ideas also appreciated. (Binary, Text or anything else)?

Comment: can you show us the table definition?

Comment: 21g is big? I have a 800gb database at home and a 6000gb database at work. How you call those? Hint: 21gb is small. ANYTHING a medium server (64gb these days) can keep in memory is small.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 has some built in [data compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that would be worth looking at.

Comment: IIRC not in the free / lower end version, and anyone complaining about a 21gb database (heck, we have a 32gb temp database on most servers - the smaller ones) will not use the enterprise edition ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store it, you have to store it.

Are you sure you gotta store it? Can't you throw away the old ones?

Second, isn't disk space cheaper than programmer time? Just asking.